# Extracting a file name from path

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the files name for a path. But every time I run this code below I only get the name of the parent folder instead

```
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root,file)
            print(path)
            label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))
            print(label)
```

I get these results :

```
D:\AI\Deep learning\face generator\images\chris evans 1.jpg
images
D:\AI\Deep learning\face generator\images\chris evans 2.jpg
images
```

and so on

My expected results are

```
D:\AI\Deep learning\face generator\images\chris evans 1.jpg
chris evans 1.jpg
D:\AI\Deep learning\face generator\images\chris evans 2.jpg
chris evans 2.jpg
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, use correct upper case letters and provide a better view of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) (Python >= 3.4) for this.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('D:\AI\Deep learning\face generator\images\chris evans 1.jpg')
filename = p.name
print(filename)
```